# How do I gather information about the scrollbar in JQuery, specifically whether it is being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a function which runs based on a `setInterval()` call. It looks like this:

```
function update()
{
    destinationY = targetPage.offset().top - $("div#reel").offset().top;
    currentY -= (currentY - destinationY) / REEL_EASE;

    $(document).scrollTop(currentY);
}
```

This updates the position of the document constantly to give the effect of a sliding animation, sliding towards certain points which are stored by the navigation items.

I want to not run the above code if the scrollbar has been clicked on the page. How can I call a method when the scrollbar is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect when the bar itself is clicked. The closest you can get is attaching a handler to `window.onscroll`, which is fired only when the scrollbar's position changes (clicking to scroll or mouse wheel up/down to scroll).

http://jsfiddle.net/CTHCe/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer, but you should be able to use the scroll event to keep track of whether the scrollbar is being used:
http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: That seems to fire when the above in my question is called as well though, ideas?

Comment: This sounds similar to what you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop