# How to disable scrolling until animation is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am using this code to scroll to a certain element on my page:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".myDiv").offset().top}, 300);
```

It works, but there is one issue with it: When the user scrolls down while the script scrolls up, there is some juddering because there are two scroll commands at the same time in different directions - sounds logical to me.

I checked some other sites with such scroll functionality, there is no juddering. So what's the trick to prevent this?

Comment: on which event are you using this: $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".myDiv").offset().top}, 300); can you explain more please.

Comment: are you using this with hover or click or somethingelse?

Comment: I use it on click, like `$("somehting").click(function() { ... });`

Comment: come plz http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14079/fast-solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thats a jQuery bug when you use animate with scrolling, good detection.

I did a research how to turn it off scrolling and find this question : [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

[Here is jsFiddle. You will see after click; user cant scroll untill animate complete.](http://jsfiddle.net/prSqz/17/)

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){

    disable_scroll();

    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700,function() {
        enable_scroll();
    });
});
```

edit: thanks to galambalazs btw.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to galambalazs' answer. If anyone else ends up here, I've refactored his solution into a nice self-contained object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21533631/940252

Answer (score 0):

an idea - try hooking to the scroll event and use http://api.jquery.com/stop/ to stop your animation
.. bad idea..

same problem with a solution - [let user scrolling stop jquery animation of scrolltop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop)