# How to block/disable scrolling for seconds on page load with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, load

I am using this code, for making page scroll down to a class on page load:

```
    $(function(){
            $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({
                scrollTop: $('.myDiv').offset().top
            }, 2000);
            return false;
        });
```

When page load, and i scroll contemporary with the animation it conflicts. How can I disable scrolling during the delay - or before the animation starts.

I have searched and found several examples of how to disable scrolling on a [click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649456/how-to-disable-scrolling-until-animation-is-complete), but I can't figure out to implement it into my code.

Thank you . I really hope you can help me. Excuse my english.

Comment: Did you have luck with this? How did you feel about the UX of it, I'm curious. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide scrolling on page load by setting overflow to hidden

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Run a settimeout for 2 seconds and then set overflow to auto and then animate like this

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('html, body')
    .css({
      'overflow': 'auto'
    })
    .animate({
      scrollTop: $('.myDiv').offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/duhigi/1/)

Using delay is fine but its functionality is limited as mentioned in the docs [`here`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.