# How to stop scrollLeft animation on user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have the following code here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.scrolls').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft : 4000
    },100000, 'linear')
})
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to stop the animation as soon as the user interacts with the scrollbar within that div. I'm a jquery newb so if anyone could help me out, would be MUCH appreciated!

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BMb65/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop

Comment: That answer works on the jsfiddle, but doesn't work on my website.  I'm using mamp right now, running wordpress, and first, it doesn't seem to recognize this part
    var $viewport = $('.scrolls');
and if I change all the $viewport to $('.scrolls'), the animation will start, but won't stop.  So it's not recognizing the .bind portion.  I'm a jquery newb, so I don't know WHY it's not doing it, but it isn't.  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to stop the animation on click and it worked I think all you need to do is to decide what events you want to listen for:

I used:

```
    $(".scrolls").on("click",function(){
        $(this).stop(true,false);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMb65/9/)