# Scrolltop function shakes the website when it is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem on my website. I have used the following line in my javascript

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 1000);
```

here is my javascript function

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 39) { 
        var $next, $selected = $(".current");
            $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
            $selected.removeClass("current");
            $next.addClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 1000);
            showPage(parseInt($next.text())) 
    }
});


$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 37) { 
            var $prev, $selected = $(".current");

            $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
            $selected.removeClass("current");
            $prev.addClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 1000);
            showPage(parseInt($prev.text())) 

}
    });
```

So, when I press left or right arrow, it animates and scrolls up to a specified `div` as its supposed to be. But when I try scrolling down, windows shakes and not letting me scroll down. I am not able to figure the problem and make it smoother.

**Update**

here is my [webpage](http://goo.gl/o6VXQZ)

Comment: please include a sample of your HTML where the classes used in the JS are being used. ( e.g. .single-post-content )

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted the question by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a simple catch that will cancel animation on user interaction.  Something like this should work:

```
$(document).on("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel") {
        $('html, body').stop();
    }
});
```

This was modified from a related issue: [let user scrolling stop jquery animation of scrolltop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop)

Comment: I tried adding your code. I dont think it worked. Also I have updated my question

Comment: I updated my code sample to run `stop` on the correct selector.  I tested on your site and it appears to work.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the scroll animation is still active while you are trying to scroll which forces a certain offset. if you wait a couple seconds between pressing direction keys and scrolling everything works. using `stop()` seems the right way to go. or make the animation time short `400` instead of `1000`

Comment: I think it still kind of wobbling on chrome. On Safari and Firefox it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create using this code

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").height()}, 800);
```

instead of 
            `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 1000);enter code here`