# Smooth Scrolling to anchor with the ability to interrupt animation with scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet of Jquery for smooth scrolling to an anchor:

```
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

to take you to...

```
<a name="home"></a>
```

.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
$root.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
}, 500, function () {
    window.location.hash = href;
});
return false;
});
```

it works great but is there a way to stop the animation if you scroll again, right now this has to finish the 500ms and goes jittery when try to scroll whilst it animates...

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Where in your document is the JavaScript located?

Comment: Also, change ``<a name="home"></a>`` to ``<a id="home"></a>`` because ``#`` refers to an ``id``, not a ``name``.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks, its a link in the head using the google api libraries link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Credit to @TomBates from his answer to [let user scrolling stop jquery animation of scrolltop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop/#10144683)

```js
var $root = $('html, body');

$('a').click(function() {
  var href = $.attr(this, 'href');

  $root.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
  }, 500, function() {
    window.location.hash = href;
  });

  return false;
});

$root.bind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchstart', function(e) {
  if (e.which > 0 || e.type === 'mousedown' || e.type === 'mousewheel' || e.type === 'touchstart') {
    $root.stop();
  }
});
```

```css
.home, .footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.home {
    background-color: #0FF;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
    <a id="home"></a>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: After the code you provided, in a context where ``$root`` is defined.

Comment: so like var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 10000, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $root.stop();
});      ? Sorry jquery novice :)

Comment: @OllyF Please provide the relevant HTML in your question, otherwise there's no way I can tell whether it works or not.